# Consolidate 3 windows services which are exact same but with different connection string settings

Tags: windows, service

I have 3 separate windows service projects that does exact same thing. The only difference is that each project file has different connection string setting in the app.config.
I am planning to consolidate the service project to make it more manageable. What is the best approach?

**Current Scenario:**

> 3 win services > executes every 6 minutes > hits 3 different databases >
>   collects data > generates XML > sends the XML to the FTP.

**Expected Result:**

> 1 win service > executes every 6 minutes > hits 3 different databases >
>   collects data > generates XML > sends the XML to the FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So they all do the same thing baring the have different connection strings - "easy".

Within your config create a new app setting in the config for "schemas" or something the same and have the values separated with a comma eg:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="schema" value="connection1, connection2, connection3"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then in your  ensure you have a key for each one of the connections in the schema app setting key

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection1" connectionString="your_connection_string" providerName="the_providor"/>
    <add name="connection2" connectionString="your_connection_string" providerName="the_providor"/>
    <add name="connection3" connectionString="your_connection_string" providerName="the_providor"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In your OnStart do something as follows - baring in mind a sleep or thread itteration is needed to be put in but you get the idea:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    string[] schemaList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["schema"].Split(",".ToCharArray());

    foreach (string schema in schemaList)
    {
        // do your stuff...
    }
```

Comment: Can you think of any performance hits? The service generates and sends 50-100 XML files to the FTP in one shot for each client db.

Comment: Honestly no; I have something similar where I work that connects to several Oracle and MSSQL databases and the only thing I really ever worry about is the server going down for maintenance.